# How to transform a matplotlib figure containing patches to a plotly figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-python

I would like to integrate some figures containing patches in my plotly workflow. I generated them using matplotlib patches and try to transform the plot with plotly.tools.mpl_to_plotly. However, only regular plots seem to be converted using this function, my patches are lost.
Is there any way to convert patch containing plots into plotly? 
Minimal (non-) working example using exemplary code from the matplotlib page:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.tools as tls

vertices = []
codes = []

codes = [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.LINETO]*3 + [Path.CLOSEPOLY]
vertices = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (0, 0)]

codes += [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.LINETO]*2 + [Path.CLOSEPOLY]
vertices += [(4, 4), (5, 5), (5, 4), (0, 0)]

vertices = np.array(vertices, float)
path = Path(vertices, codes)

pathpatch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='None', edgecolor='green')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(pathpatch)
ax.set_title('A compound path')

ax.autoscale_view()

import plotly.tools as tls
tls.mpl_to_plotly(fig)
```

Thanks!

Comment: plotly can only draw paths that belong to bar charts, as seen [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/65625d49226632abcf932d530aa9c90ba1bc59c1/packages/python/plotly/plotly/matplotlylib/renderer.py#L481) in the source code.